# ASP.NET Core Filtered Dropdown List does not display previously entered value

Tags: asp.net-core, selectlist

I have an ASP.NET Core web application with a dropdown list on an edit page.  It is a SQL back-end.  One of my fields is "Project Manager" which populated from the "Users" table.

So people do not select retired or inactive users, there is a Boolean field in SQL called "Active" which is true for active users and false for former users.

I filter my select list based on this attribute and it correctly displays only current users.

However, if an existing record has an inactive user in the Project Manager field, it shows as null when you open the edit page.

Is there a way to retain the existing value on the edit page when the value does not exist in the select list?

Alternately, is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In case of no records you can Concat the 'Default' data with you list. With this if your list returns empty records, it will be concated with default and there will be one default option.

OR

You can Set some hardcode value for the dropdown list if it return null or empty. In this case your hardcoded data will be populated on UI if no records found in list.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work using the following:

```
@{
  if (Model.Projects.ProjectManager.HasValue &&
      Model.Projects.ProjectManagerNavigation.Active == false)
         {
         int pm = (int)Model.Projects.ProjectManager;
<option value="@pm">@Model.Projects.ProjectManagerNavigation.FullName</option>
         }
         else
         {<option disabled selected>--- SELECT ---</option>}
  }
```

Inside of the Select Tag for that field.

It checks if the Project Manager field has a value, and if that user is Inactive and just adds a select list option for the existing  user, even though they are no longer in the filtered select list.

Thanks for the answer Sachin, I just needed to work out how to get that implemented.